# Build string pyramid

Tags: javascript

Help me solve this is there some one can solve this?? im stuck

let word = 'foxie'
//output
e
ei
xie
eixo
foxie

````
example 2:
```javascript
let word = '3oz4spoon'
//output 
n
no
oon
noop
spoon
noops4
z4spoon
noops4zo
3oz4spoon
````

Comment: What are you actually trying to do here?

Answer (score 0):

```
let word = "foxie";

 function reverseString(string) {
    return string.split("").reverse().join("");
 }

 for (let i = 1; i <= word.length; i++) {
   
   if (i === word.length) {
      console.log(word);
   } else {
      console.log(reverseString(word.slice(word.length - i)));
   }
 }

// output:
   e 
   ei 
   eix 
   eixo 
   foxie
```

Comment: if you mind may you help me with another problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
function printPyramid(word, index = 0) {
  if (index % 2 === 0) {
    console.log(word.slice(word.length - index - 1));
  } else {
    console.log(word.slice(word.length - index - 1).split('').reverse().join(''));
  }
  if (word.length === index + 1) {
    return;
  }
  printPyramid(word, index + 1)
}

printPyramid('foxie')
```